# Using jQuery to toggle divs, AND hidden divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok fine folks of Stack Overflow, I have a question and I can't seem to figure this out. I've tried for a while now, but I can't seem to get this thing straight, and I'm hoping you can help.

Please take a look at this page:

http://ec2-50-16-99-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com/aptify/rocks/global-rocks.aspx

Notice the button towards the top of the page that says "show less info" If you click on that, this should hide two of the elements inside towards the right of each of these grey data bars, I'm calling them "rocks".

Now, that works fine. The problem arises when I show the child "rocks" of each of these elements after I've already clicked on "show less info." You can click on the "plus" button and toggle the children to see what I mean.

If you toggle the children, the elements that are supposed to hide when you click "show less info" are not hidden. But the elements who's widths have changed ARE changed.

So the question is: if I've got some hidden elements by default, how do I get jQuery to hide an element that is within an element set to `display: none`? Is there some kind of way or method to have jQuery change the hidden elements as well so that when I toggle these new elements they are also changed?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

**SOLUTION**

I got it working now, thanks to your help. Here's my callback function (in case anyone ever runs into this issue).

```
$('.kpi,.edit-nav').fadeOut(200,function(){
   $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would toggle a class on each `section.rock-accordion` whenever "show more info" is clicked.  Keep your animations, but giving the parent a class (or lack of that class) will allow you to control all of its children, not just the currently visible ones.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is going to be my best bet. The only thing I'm apprehensive about is losing the fadeIn/fadeOut animations. But of course that's a better option than having it look ridiculous when you toggle the children.

Comment: I think you can preserve the animations by toggling the class in the fadeIn/fadeOut callback.

Comment: @skybondsor is right, you must use callbacks to ensure all your content is shown correctly before and after.

Comment: yeah, I should have thought of that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is it is called `toggle()` here is a link to its description http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Yeah, I understand toggle. In fact, I'm using it on the example. Have you had a chance to take a look at the page? It toggles the widths on a hidden element fine, but it doesn't set the element to `display: none` on elements inside of a hidden div. The question is "how do I make it do that?"

Comment: $("#someId").css('display', 'none');- is this enough

Comment: Apply a callback function and set it in there using the css method

Comment: Well the .css('display','none') would work ok, but if you look at the example I showed, I'm already using a toggle function with `.fadeIn();` and `.fadeOut();` which basically is an animation of `.css('display','none);` That doesn't work.

Comment: let me rephrase - the fadeIn/fadeOut works fine, but it does not apply to an element that is within a div set to `display: none` - that is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Personally I like to handle all of it myself so instead of using toggle() with fadein/out(), I just use animate() and use callbacks. This gives me a lot more control of what happens. Nice looking site by the way, are you using a UI or library? Or did you design these graphics?

Comment: Hey thanks man, I designed everything myself, but I have to give premiumpixels.com, 365psd.com, and iconsweets.com some props for the icons and other elements. 

p.s. +1 for the compliments!

I'll try out the call backs. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Histro Petev, the .css() method does in fact work, however I do lose the fancy fadeIn/fadeOut effects. I'll have to keep playing with it, I guess. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You need to use the css() method in conjunction with a callback after the animation. Well, I rarely give out compliments on designs so take it well, it looks great, I just hope it functions as well as it looks when it is finished. Maybe add a copyright footer to the bottom, just to not leave it bare. All the best!

Comment: Yeah, callbacks are probably the way to go here. Thanks again on the compliments. Sites not done by a long shot- hope to launch the beta in about a month! footer will definitely be on there!